# How can i change PHP ini values in mamp pro for single host?

Tags: mamp, mamp-pro

I need to develop a website for a server that has PHP short tags set to OFF
Is it possible to set this option only for one host in MAMP PRO (4)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Mamp Pro uses one `php.ini` file for all sites but you may be able to work around this by enabling PHP Short Tags via your `.htaccess` on a site-by-site basis.

Comment: I had trouble doing this in PHP 7.2 but it works fine in PHP 7.1, it doesn't seem to have been deprecated but perhaps just a bug in Mamp 4.4.